# ¿Como saber PID de consola actual en Konsole | CentOS7?

Tags: linux, centos7

Necesito ver el PID de la consola actual que utilizo. ¿Hay algún comando para esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar `who` para ver en que terminal has iniciado sesión en mi caso pts/0

```
root@homeserver:~# who
plorenzo pts/0        2019-04-13 09:36 (192.168.1.123)
```

y luego usar `ps -A` para buscar el PID:

```
root@homeserver:~# ps -A
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
  ...
  15423 pts/0    00:00:00 zsh
```

Comment: También encontré que con echo $$.